# View multiple PDF's one after another using tkPDFViewer

Tags: python, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

I am having an issue with the tkPDFViewer library.

I want my code to basically create a slideshow of pdf's using tkinter. Right now my code adds each pdf to what's already there instead of removing the previous pdf. Please help me.

```py
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

destroy_list = []

def run():

    for thing in destroy_list:
        thing.pack_forget()
    try:
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
    except:
        pass
    item = Scans_List[0]   
    v2 = None
    v1 = None
    openfile = f"Scans\{item}"
    title_label.config(text = openfile)
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, pdf_location = openfile, bar = False, width = 66, height = 90)
    v2.pack(side = "top", anchor = "e")
    destroy_list.append(v2)
    Scans_List.remove(item)
    root.after(5000, run)
    
run()
```

Comment: It is because `v1` is a local variable, so `v1.img_object_li.clear()` always raise exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `v1` is a local variable inside `run()`, so `v1.img_object_li.clear()` always raise exception and cannot clear previous images.

One way to fix it is to pass `v1` and `v2` as arguments to run (they are `None` when it is first executed).

```py
from itertools import cycle
...
# create a cycle list of PDF files
Scan_List = cycle([...])
...
# pass v1 and v2 as arguments and they are None initially
def run(v1=None, v2=None):
    if v1 and v2:
        v1.img_object_li.clear() # clear previous images
        v2.destroy() # destroy the previous PDF content
    item = next(Scans_List)  # get next PDF file in Scan_Listt
    openfile = f"Scans\{item}"
    title_label.config(text=openfile)
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, pdf_location=openfile, bar=False, width=66, height=90)
    v2.pack(side="top", anchor="e")
    root.after(5000, run, v1, v2)

run()
...
```

Note that you can create `v1` only once instead of creating it in every `run()`:

```py
...
# create v1 only once
v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()

def run(v2=None):
    if v2:
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
        v2.destroy()
    item = next(Scans_List)
    openfile = f"Scans\{item}"
    title_label.config(text=openfile)
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, pdf_location=openfile, bar=False, width=66, height=90)
    v2.pack(side = "top", anchor = "e")
    root.after(5000, run, v2)

run()
...
```